# After INSERT/UPDATE Trigger affecting inserted rows

Tags: sql-server, triggers, query-optimization, dml

Background:
I've a table in a MS SQL database which lists a company and associated supplier and their effective from and to dates. There should only ever be one supplier active per company at one time.

The table structure is as follows;

```
_sRID    DataAreaID      Supplier     ApplicableFrom     ApplicableTo
1        Comp1           Supplier1    2018-06-01         (NULL)
2        Comp2           Supplier2    2018-06-01         (NULL)
3        Comp3           Supplier3    2018-06-01         (NULL)
```

Where _sRID is a identity.

My trigger is this;

```
   ALTER TRIGGER [trans].[ICOSupplierIDs_AutoEnd]
   ON  [trans].[ICOSupplierIDs]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    update base
    set    base.ApplicableTo = Getdate()
    from   trans.ICOSupplierIDs as base
    join   inserted as ins on ins.DataAreaID = base.DataAreaID
    where  base.ApplicableTo is null
    and    base._sRID != (select max(_sRID) from trans.ICOSupplierIDs where DataAreaID = ins.DataAreaID);

END
```

So after inserting  into the table for "comp1", the table looks as below;

```
_sRID    DataAreaID      Supplier     ApplicableFrom     ApplicableTo
1        Comp1           Supplier1    2018-06-01         2018-06-07
2        Comp2           Supplier2    2018-06-01         (NULL)
3        Comp3           Supplier3    2018-06-01         (NULL)
4        Comp1           Supplierx    2018-06-07         (NULL)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this than the end query of the max identity and hitting the table again?

TIA

Comment: im missing something here. When you say _"There should only ever be one supplier active"_ do you mean with `ApplicableTo NOT NULL`? More, the insert/update statement where comes from? Do you have control on the client where that query is running? cause it should be better to manage it without trigger...

Comment: Yes, sorry should have explained that the active supplier is determined by date, so an ApplicableTo of NULL would be the current supplier.

I do have control over the client, but I can't guarantee the bandwidth of their connection and so was trying to reduce the number of calls to the database.

Comment: Why are you using a trigger for this? Use a merge statement from your source to your target and update the row with same business key. Its simple SCD2

Comment: I need to keep a historic record of what supplier was active at one time.